# Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php, sql, admin, operand

So I am trying to write a SQL statement as follows...

> I need to Find a list of artist names, the number of CDs they have
>   produced, and the average price for their CDs. Only returning results
>   for artists with more than one CD.

Problem is every time i think ive got it I get an error reading "Operand should contain 1 column(s)", I feel as if I am being incredibly dense right now but if someone could help I would appreciate it so much.

Here is the code I have tried last..

```
SELECT Artist.artID, CD.cdPrice, Count(*)
FROM CD
INNER JOIN Artist
ON Artist.artID=(SELECT CD.artID, AVG(CD.cdPrice), COUNT(*)
                 as Count FROM CD GROUP BY CD.artID HAVING Count > 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join has three columns on the right hand side
so you could use something like

```
SELECT Artist.artID, CD.cdPrice, Count(*)
FROM CD
INNER JOIN Artist
ON Artist.artID=(SELECT CD.artID
                 FROM CD 
                 GROUP BY CD.artID 
                 HAVING Count(*) > 1)
Group by Artist.artID, CD.cdPrice
```

**ALTERNATIVE**

```
SELECT Artist.artID, CD.cdPrice, Count(*)
FROM CD
INNER JOIN Artist
ON Artist.artID=CD.artID
Group by Artist.artID, CD.cdPrice
```

**ALTERNATIVE 2**

```
SELECT Artist.artID, AVG(CD.cdPrice), Count(*)
FROM CD
INNER JOIN Artist
ON Artist.artID=CD.artID
Group by Artist.artID
Having count(*) >1
```

Comment: That still doesnt work though? that returns an error "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row "

Comment: I was only pointing out the source of the error, see the alternative and let me know why that doesn't work.

Comment: Okay well with the Alternative one, that removes the ability i believe to return the Average price and the number of CDs the artists have produced. As whenever i try and add these once more the original error reappears, Some artists have produced more than 1 CD and I need those CDs counted so it just reads the name of the artist and the number of CDs, then I just need to return only those Artists who have made more than 1 CD only..

I found using the alternative method, It just returned back to the original error when i tried to add these parameters in.

Comment: YES! that works perfectly thank you so much! I didn't realize that was how you did that thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you are saying `WHERE artID= three columns` That is the issue